# Can you upload just app metadata using Transporter?

Tags: app-store-connect

I've got an app already in the store and need to add additional IAPs using Transporter. I've used `lookupMetadata` to get the metadata.xml file. I'd like to edit this file then re-upload without having to upload the app again. Looking at the docs, the upload mode states you have to upload the app package:

> In upload mode, you must specify these command-line options:
>
> -m upload
>
> -f  or -assetFile <.ipa | .pkg> for macOS, Linux, and Windows uploads (for macOS notarization, use -assetFile <.dmg | .pkg | .zip>)
>
> -assetDescriptionAppStoreInfo.plist (-assetDescription is required for Linux and Windows uploads)
>
> -u username
>
> -p password
>
> -k kilobits_per_second *

Has anyone come across this before and is there a solution to uploading *just* the app metadata.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you can upload the itmsp file with just the metadata.xml in it and it works fine.

I validated with this:

```
iTMSTransporter -m verify -f <path to itmsp file> -u <email> -p <password> -v eXtreme
```

And uploaded with this:

```
iTMSTransporter -m upload -u <email> -p <password> -f <path to itmsp file> -k 100000 -v eXtreme
```